Error setting up Docker Standalone environment in Portainer on Windows Server
I'm trying to get Portainer running to manage Docker stuff on my Windows machine. So far, I managed to spin up the Portainer container with this command:
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v C:\portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce

Portainer itself is up and running on port 9000. But, I can't seem to add any Docker environments. The dashboard keeps telling me to add a Docker Standalone environment, so I tried setting up the Portainer agent with this:
docker run -d \
  -p 9001:9001 \
  --name portainer_agent \
  --restart=always \
  -v C:\:C:\host \
  -v C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes:C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes \
  -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine \
  portainer/agent:2.19.5

But I keep running into errors related to volume mounts and the Docker named pipe (\\.\pipe\docker_engine). At first, I got something like "invalid mode: \host" and other errors about volume paths. Now it’s complaining about "create \.\pipe\dockerDesktopEngine: ... includes invalid characters for a local volume name."
For context:

I'm on Docker Desktop for Windows (version 26.1.4).
Portainer itself is working fine on port 9000.

Any idea how to fix the command to get the Portainer agent working without these volume mount or named pipe issues? I've tried tweaking it but nothing’s worked so far.

